# I was working with a premade Geralt Model and was having trouble with the hair

Tags: modeling, shaders, hair

I got the model from here: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/witcher-3-geralt-8f62c76580144ed2a8c648dd5046d8d9
Attached bellow is the an image of the current problem I having with the beard and hair textures. There is two objects for the hair and three different objects for the beard. Along with my problem is the current node setup I have for both the hair objects. The beard node setup is the same but without the normal map and file.

[image: this is the problem I am having with the beard and hair textures. They go black and white][image: this is my current node set up for the both of the hair models. The beard is similar but without the _n (normal) png file]

Comment: I didnt checked source, but from screen i can see you dont have assigned alpha channel.

Comment: @vklidu so I would just take my hair_d and plug that into the alpha channel of the shader as well?

Answer (score 0):

*Image Texture* node *Alpha* to *Principle BSDF Alpha* ... *Blend mode* **Alpha Clip** under material setting is OK.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this out later